# Access list names in JSON file

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON dataset with scheduling information.

```json
{
  "admin-1": {
    "username": "user0",
    "current_amount_of_patients": 0,
    "on_break": false,
    "scheduling_type": 2,
    "schedule": {
      "Monday": [
        "17:00:00"
      ],
      "Tuesday": [
        "17:00:00",
        "18:00:00"
      ],
      "Wednesday": [
        "10:00:00",
        "11:00:00",
        "12:00:00",
        "13:00:00"
      ]
    },
    "com_type": 1
  },
  "admin-2": {
    "username": "user1",
    "on_break": false,
    "scheduling_type": 1,
    "timezone": "America/Los_Angeles",
    "schedule": {
      "Tuesday": [
        "17:00:00",
        "18:00:00"
      ],
      "Wednesday": [
        "10:00:00",
        "11:00:00",
        "12:00:00",
        "13:00:00"
      ],
      "Sunday": [
        "09:00:00",
        "10:00:00",
        "11:00:00",
        "12:00:00"
      ]
    },
    "com_type": 2
  }
}
```

I'd like to access only the names of the days and put them in lists for every user. Meaning, the output would be:

```py
days = [['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday'], ['Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Sunday']]
```

I tried doing it this way:

```py
days = [user["schedule"].keys() for user in data.values()]
```

But it didn't give any output. Note that I'm doing it in a for loop in case I'll add more users to the database.

Do you have any ideas of how to make it work to the desired output?

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. Make a [mre]. Maybe you're reading the wrong JSON file or something. For more tips, like how to write a good title, see [ask].

Comment: Yeah, so I think the issue might have been that not all user profiles in my code had a key name called "schedule". My bad on that, should've included it.

Comment: You'd get a `KeyError` in that case.

Comment: Yeah, I did. In the finalized code, all users will have a key name called `"schedule"`. However, not all users will have a schedule, so that value would be `null`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try (`your_data.json` file contains the Json from your question):

```py
import json

with open("data.json", "r") as f_in:
    data = json.load(f_in)

days = [list(d["schedule"] or []) for d in data.values()]
print(days)
```

Prints:

```
[['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday'], ['Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Sunday']]
```

Comment: This really isn't that much different than their proposed answer. I suggest clarifying with OP.

Comment: I think this answer might work. I forgot to tell that some user profiles won't have schedules, meaning `"schedule"` would equal to `null`. How can I still iterate through it and just add None to the list?

Comment: @EliahsJohansson If some `schedule` keys contains `null`, you can substitute it with empty list `[]`. I've updated my answer.